# Fast API mail Error: 535, '5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled

Tags: python, authentication, office365, fastapi, outlook-restapi

I am working on a small fast api call to send a simple email using my outlook account. This is the code I have so far:

```
class EmailSchema(BaseModel):
     email: List[EmailStr]

conf = ConnectionConfig(
   MAIL_USERNAME="personal outlook email",
   MAIL_PASSWORD="personal outlook email password",
   MAIL_FROM = "personal outlook email",
   MAIL_PORT=587,
   MAIL_SERVER="smtp.office365.com",
   MAIL_STARTTLS = True,
   MAIL_SSL_TLS = False
)


@app.post("/email")
async def simple_send(email: EmailSchema):
    html = """
    <html>
    <body>
    <h5>This is a test mail sent from fast API</h5>
    </body>
    </html>
    """

    message = MessageSchema(
        subject="This is a test email subject",
        recipients=email.dict().get("email"),
        body=html,
        subtype=MessageType.html)


    fm = FastMail(conf)
    await fm.send_message(message)
    return JSONResponse(status_code=200, content={"message": "email has been sent"})
```

when running the above code, I get the error "message fastapi_mail.errors.ConnectionErrors: Exception raised (535, '5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, basic authentication is disabled. check your credentials or email service configuration"

I have played around with the configuration settings in the code above, but nothing seems to work. I also looked up the error message above and it seems like some people got away with disabling authenticated client SMTP on their outlook account for it to work. But I dont want to do that for security reasons.

Is there a solution to this error, or do I possibly have the configuration settings wrong in the code above? I am still new to fast api, so im not 100% sure of whats going wrong here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70954881/535-5-7-139-authentication-unsuccessful-smtpclientauthentication-is-disabled-fo)